# What will Anime and Manga.SE look like when we graduate?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering, but since the site will be graduating really soon from the looks of it, have we decided what the design will be when we graduate?

There is a related question here on this [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/what-should-our-site-design-look-like), which asks what **should** our site look like, but have we actually decided on what it **will** look like and who actually decides? Is it voted on by the community, do the moderators decide? ect...

Comment: In the meantime, you can help propose a mascot for us: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/848/63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is owned by Stack Exchange, and as such they get to determine the design of the site.

Because it's a community site, we get a say and like you've seen we were brainstorming on the other meta thread at the request of the Stack Exchange designer, Jin.

Truth be told, even us, the moderators don't know what the site is going to look like, so until further announcements here on meta, we're all waiting. :-)

Comment: Im just hoping its less bright, this white stuff is killing me at night.