# Is the design for Anime SE still in progress?

Tags: discussion, design

Are there any progress for re-designing the Anime StackExchange site ? Or is that post just a "proposal" or discussion that will be done in the near future ?

[Hey! Listen! Let's have a talk about our site design! (The Idea Gathering 2015 Edition)](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/hey-listen-lets-have-a-talk-about-our-site-design-the-idea-gathering-2015-e)

Comment: Don't worry it will be Soon™. Do you have a cool idea or concept? Share it here! What kind of style represents anime to you?

Comment: well... i dont know... maybe other will :'.. i am not into UX so i dont understand :'( ... @кяαzєя. Thanks !. But i am so hyped about this, can't wait for this to happen

Comment: You don't need to be into UX or UI to care what something should look like. Just tell us things you'd like to see.

Comment: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/the-anime-and-manga-unofficial-design-wip?rq=1

Comment: We can only cross our fingers since [the last site design was on Oct 2016 (last year)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/241919). Better use user-style mentioned in Darjeeling's comment if you want to have something that's not so plain.

Comment: While it's possible, I kind of doubt there is any work happening toward this right now. We've now been waiting for 4 years for a design. For the sites that have had designs made, it took just a matter of weeks between when the design team began work and when they had a draft ready. If this was a priority for them, it could have happened at any point; I can't see anything to suggest that there would somehow be a shift of priorities *now*...

Comment: Rather, my (perhaps unfair) opinion is that in the past couple years SE has been much more focused on marketting and ads, leading to a large focus on SO, Jobs, and developer-related features, to the detriment of the greater SE community. Of course, only an SE employee can definitively answer this question, but if they're too busy to pay any attention to this it wouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: I don't even want a different design anymore. *This* is A&M's design to me. If it were anything else, it would take a bit of time to get used to. Designs shouldn't be annoying first of all, so if the design team decides to copy just about any of the usual "anime site" designs with random art, it's gonna be annoying. Maybe if they come up with an almost invisible pattern of vaguely anime-related icons, it will be alright, but anything more prominent than that I don't think will be generally well received.

Comment: @Hakase i would probably kind like this design  

https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/the-anime-and-manga-unofficial-design-wip?rq=1

Comment: @Gagantous yea those grey sides and unreadable tags… I mean the beauty is in the eye of the beholder :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, a design for this community’s not currently being actively worked on. The design team is stretched pretty thin at the moment, and no new designs are being worked on for the foreseeable future — which means I can’t give you an estimate for when a design for our site would be rolled out.

I know that's a frustrating answer, but I'd rather be totally realistic and open with you, than unduly optimistic.

Comment: Thanks for the update, even if it isn't what we hoped for. In light of this, have there been any updates on https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009? With no designs for the forseeable future and with 10 sites already in the graduated-but-not-designed state (and presumably more to come), it seems like the reputation limits will always remain at the current low levels unless the policy is changed toward this.

Comment: We discussed it internally when that post was brought up, but I don't remember where we got at the moment — will bring it up again and post updates there as soon as I have 'em ;)

Comment: out of curiosity, i have seen your stack profile, and you are a moderator of 171 site ??? how could you handle that ?

Comment: @Gagantous He is an employee for Stack Overflow, hence the moderator everywhere.

Comment: i see... thanks @Dimitrimx

Comment: Then, just asking for new logo is still a bit too much I guess?

Comment: For the time being, I'm afraid so, @Darjeeling :\